# CoreData To-One relationship: object is nil after relaunch application

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity-relationship

I'm creating an object and it's relationship, everything is working fine, but after I relaunch the app, the relationships are lost. Searched and tried few things I found on the web and here, but without success..

There is object called DbTopic which is the object which the user is saving to favorites. I've created an object called DbFavorite, which have a relationship to the DbTopic.

This is my code:

```
func addToFavorites(topic: DbTopic) {
    let favObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "DbFavorites", into: self.managedObjectContext()) as! DbFavorites
    favObject.topicId = topic.id
    favObject.topic = topic
    topic.favorite = favObject

    do {
        try self.managedObjectContext().save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("DEBUG: Failure while saving context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

ManagedObjectContent:

```
func managedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

Save Context:

```
func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

After relaunching the app, I try to print the objects saved to DbFavorite, there are objects by the .topic is nil.

This is the relationships:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please can you edit your question to show the code for `managedObjectContext()`?

Comment: Off-topic but you don't need to set both directions of a relation ship when you have defined the inverse. So either `favObject.topic = topic` _or_ `topic.favorite = favObject` is enough, you don't need both

Comment: @pbasdf I've edited the question... thanks!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I know that, but figured it might be something to do with the issue im experiencing...

Comment: Have you checked so that you do not delete the `topic` object at a later stage?

Comment: Are you adding the same topic to favourites more than once?  Because the relationship is one-to-one, when you assign a topic to a new favourite, the old favourite will have its topic set to nil.

Comment: What @JoakimDanielson said about _both direction_ is true. But `favObject.topicId = topic.id` seems strange too. If you set `favObject.topic = topic` then the `id` attribute will be available anyway via `favObject.topic.id`. [Core Data Debugging](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/core-data-debugging-xcode/) might be helpful.